# How to remote upload a video directly to my FTP server?

Tags: php, upload, ftp, youtube

I consider myself a skilled googler, however, I've had a lot of trouble finding *any* information regarding this matter. So, what I'm trying to do is create a PHP script that will fetch a video (in this case from YouTube) from their server directly to my FTP server. I'm not very good with PHP, unfortunately.

All that I've found so far simply retrieves a download link from YouTube and gives you an option to download it directly to your computer. This is not what I want.

I have PHP 5.3.14 installed on my Apache server. Safe mode is off and open basedir is on. I'm open to any and all suggestions. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: yes, there might not be the exact guide for what you want, but there should be plenty for 1) getting the url from a youtube video, 2) downloading a file with php. 3) uploading a file to ftp with PHP.

Comment: I really haven't found anything, except for the scripts that give you a link to download to your computer and not your server.

Comment: Uku Loskit: I haven't had a problem with number 1. It's just that I find it difficult to combine 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't gonna sound much like an answer but then you give us so little to go on:

On your FTP server you would run a PHP script which polls every, say 1 min Youtube search rsults and scrapes URLs to their servers (I think Youtube actually messes you up if you hotlink in this manner). With this script you would basically do a chunked cURL download to one of your directories and bingo! done...

Simple as pie.

Well actually pie is harder to make...but you get the idea

In fact to get you started here is how to cURL a file down:

```
function cURL_file($url){
    set_time_limit(0);
    $fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__)."/input_file", 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 75);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Send in the URL and it will make a file in your PHP scripts directory called input_file containing the data.

This of course would actually run as a cronjob on your ftp server scheduled for probably once a minute.

#### Edit

Ok so for a form.

I would make a form (ofc) with one field called url. When submitted it will go to this script called, youtube_url_grabber.php:

```
cURL_file($_POST['url']); // This calls the function with the url the user entered.

function cURL_file($url){
    set_time_limit(0);
    $fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__)."/input_file", 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 75);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

So the forms `action` will point to this here script.

Of course do not actually use this script else you'll get your sever abused and hacked almost immediately but this should tell you how to download the file some one enters onto your own server.

Now I would imagine your FTP server is not the same server that your from is running on so after cURLing the file down to your server you will want to move it onto your FTP server. To save me writing all that code I am just gonna link the first search results on google: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/ftp-example.htm .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but now I'm confused. Maybe I have bitten more than I can chew here but I didn't understand a whole lot of your response. Let me explain a little more clear.

`$ch = curl_init("http://site.com/link/to/video.mp4");
$fp = fopen("files/video.mp4", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);`

So, what I want is for this code to be "automated", preferably with an HTML <form> to enter the URL and desired filename.

Comment: I couldn't get the form working, but thanks anyway, you've been very helpful!

Comment: Yea look into PHP a bit more, you may have bitten off a bit more than you can chew. Once you got PHP skills you can use this post for reference.

Comment: I just found out from my host that PHP processes will no longer be able to create files larger than 128MB (134217728 bytes). Which is sad, because most of the HD videos on YT are larger than this. So, this might be in vain, but is there any way to bypass this somehow? Maybe trick the server to think I'm not using PHP somehow?

Comment: @Northstreamer try reading some of this: http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php I must admit this was the first one I found and could have wrote it here but hopefully this will help,

Comment: @Northstreamer To be more explicit with my reply, try upping the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size config setting in PHP

Comment: My host doesn't let me change the PHP config file. Maybe you can "split" the download in parts?

Comment: @Northstreamer That function already does that to conserve memory. I suppose you could make a multipart downloader in cURL but I fear that would be....well hard for you if I am honest. You have already admitted your skills in PHP are not really upto scratch.

Comment: Yeah, I trust you. Another problem that I've had is that files end up like 0B, despite the link being accurate. PHP is weird...

Comment: @Northstreamer It is probably because Youtube is either blocking you or the file is greater than 128meg

Comment: Yup, they have begun with IP-blocking now.

Comment: Just to let ya know, I sent you an email. I don't have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: @Northstreamer Ah you sent it to that email, ok kool I'll try and look at it, may take my a while....

Answer (score 0):

actually I'm using rapidleech
http://www.rapidleech.com
to fetch videos from you tube to my server and i can modify them and remotely upload them to to my youtube channel
so i trans load the video to my server and upload them once again
it allows you to choose the download format
i use it to backup my channel to my server (2000 videos) because i have slow connection